# MySQL join causes a CONVERT( USING utf16) on two varchar cols

Tags: mysql

I have two `tables`, `stock` & `prices`.

Please can someone explain why CONVERT is being called internally. Both fields are of the same type and length.

`stock` contains `product_id` VARCHAR(128)

`prices` contains `sku` VARCHAR(128)

The query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT * FROM prices 
JOIN stock ON prices.sku = stock.product_id;
```

Looking at the result of `EXPLAIN` it states a `ref` of `func`

Calling `SHOW WARNINGS;` returns the query

```
SELECT * FROM `prices`
JOIN `stock`
WHERE (
    `prices`.`sku` = CONVERT(`stock`.`product_id` USING utf16)
)
```

I'm hopeful resolving this will help my performance issues.

The result of the explain is:

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "filtered"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "stock" "ALL"   \N  \N  \N  \N  "128715"    "100.00"    ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "prices"    "ref"   "sku_channel,sku"   "sku_channel"   "515"   "func"  "1" "100.00"    "Using index condition"
```

I came to the conclusion CONVERT is being called due to the result returned from `SHOW WARNINGS`

Comment: Where are the result of `EXPLAIN.. ` statement in your question ? How did you come to the conclusion that `CONVERT` is being done ? What is your table structure ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the result of EXPLAIN. I came to the conclusion CONVERT is being done because of the query returned from `SHOW WARNINGS`. If you feel the full table structure is relevant please let me know and I will include it.

Comment: What is the collation on both `prices.sku` and `stock.product_id`?

Comment: @RacilHilan prices is `utf16_general_ci` stock is `latin_swedish_ci`. Do you think that could be whats causing the convert?

Comment: @RacilHilan I've made both `latin_swedish_ci` still seeing the convert :(

Comment: Did you just change the default charset of the table? That doesn't change the existing columns, it only sets a default to be used for future columns you add. If you want to convert existing columns use `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

Comment: @BillKarwin thats done it, many thanks to you + Racil! If you want to provide an answer would be happy to accept. Would also love to know why it needs to perform the CONVERT

Comment: Bill has provided a good answer, but yes, the `Convert` clearly indicated that the collation on the two columns didn't match. The collation is encoding which defines the characters and relationship between them. The same character can be encoded differently in different collations, so the database cannot compare them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just do a simple string comparison between strings of different collations. Collations tell MySQL how to evaluate if a given character is equal to another. But this only works within the same collation. So if you try to compare strings of different collations, MySQL has to convert one or the other string to the collation of the other before the strings can be compared.

This means doing a JOIN between strings of different collations will have to convert the string on every row, even rows where the strings don't match, before it can evaluate the JOIN condition.

You should make sure you are comparing strings that both use the same collation.

When you tried to use `ALTER TABLE ... CHARACTER SET = ...` this doesn't change the existing columns. It only changes the *default* character set for the table, which only affects new columns you add to the table.

To change existing columns to a different character set, use `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ...`.

Read the section **Changing the Character Set** in this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html for complete information.